# Prove that for a positive number only exists one natural number such that $b{++} = a$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, induction

My first time on Mathematics, thank you for your attention and patience.

Eventually, I decided to have a taste of mathematical analysis, useful for my University. My weapon of choice is Terence Tao's *Analysis 1*. I love its style. It is making me clear a lot of things that before were cause of headaches. Unfortunately, it does not provide exercise solutions allowing me to test the product of my efforts.

I am trying to solve the Exercise 2.2.2:

> Let $a$ be a positive number. Then there exists exactly one natural
> number $b$ such that $b{++}=a$.

The author suggests to use induction. Frankly, I have no idea how to induct on such a problem. My approach used another way:

1. $a \neq 0$ by definition of positive natural number;
2. Peano's Axiom 4 states that different natural numbers must have different successors;
3. Hence, if $b{++} = a$ and $c{++} = a$ then $b = c$, contradicting the lemma stating that $\exists! (b{++} = a)$.

   The same problem is faced in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113147/proving-every-positive-natural-number-has-unique-predecessor), but I found it quite confusing.
   Is my approach acceptable? How should induction work on such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have *uniqueness* as a consequence of axiom 4.

In order to show *existence,* I'd still suggest to use induction (though it is a very trivial induction proof that does not even use the induction hypothesis)

Comment: I am a newbie of the field. I am afraid that I am still not capable to properly apply induction on this kind of problem. The base case is $b = 0$. If $b = 0$ and $b++ = a$, by Axiom 4 no other natural number $n$ can truly provide $n++ = a$, because otherwise $n = b$. Now let's suppose that we inductively proved that $n++ = a$. I could repeat what I have done before with the base case: if $m++ = a$ them $m = n$, and this is not possible by Ax. 4, but I am not convinced by the approach I tried.