# $4x≡2\mod5$ can you divide both sides by $2$ to get $2x≡1\mod5\,?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Since gcd$(2,5)=1$ , could you treat $4x$ as $2(2x)$ and cancel the $2$ on both sides?
i.e. $$2(2x)≡2\mod5\implies 2x≡1\mod5$$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. $4x=2\bmod5$ means 5 divides $4x-2=2(2x-1)$. It does not divide 2, so it must divide $2x-1$.

Comment: ahh of course I didn't think it through, thank you!

Comment: you could also multiply both sides by $3\equiv2^{-1}\pmod5$ to get $2x\equiv1\pmod5$ ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short  , **Yes** you can$^1$ .

$$4x\equiv 2\mod5 \implies 4x -2 = 5\lambda$$

Notice that L.H.S is divisible by $2$ , which implies that R.H.S **must** also be divisible by $2$ or $\lambda = 2\alpha$. So our equation becomes :

$$2(2x-1) = 5\cdot2\alpha\implies 2x-1\equiv \mod 5 \implies \color{#4d0}{2x \equiv 1\mod5}$$

---

$(1.)$ Note that in $ax \equiv b \mod c$ ,  if G.C.D$(a,b) = k$ , such that $k\mid c$ then :

$$ax\equiv b \mod c \implies \color {#c03}{\frac ak \equiv \frac bk \mod \frac ck}$$

For example , consider  $4x \equiv 2 \mod 6$ , this equivalent to

$$4x\equiv 2\mod 6 \implies 2(2x-1) = 6\lambda$$
$$(2x-1) = 3\lambda \implies \color{#d0d}{2x\equiv 1 \mod 3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. $4x \equiv 2 \mod5 \implies 4x - 2 = 5k \implies 2(2x-1)=5k \implies 5$ divides $2x-1$ as $\gcd(2,5)=1 \implies 2x \equiv 1 \pmod5$

Note:  please feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: I edited your answer . Hope you don't have a problem.

Comment: No problems, thanks :)

Comment: Another suggestion , Avoid writing answers similar to which have already been posted . I have already posted a similar answer in more depth .

Answer (score 1):

THEOREM $1$. If

- $ax \equiv b \pmod n$
- $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$
- $\gcd(d,n)=1$

then
$\dfrac adx \equiv \dfrac bd \pmod n$

PROOF.

If $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$, then there exists integers, $A$ and $B$, such that $a = dA$ and $b =dB$.

If $\gcd(d,n)=1$, then there exists integers, D and E, such that $Dd + nE = 1$. It follows that $Dd \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

So 
\begin{align}
   ax \equiv b \pmod n 
      &\implies dAx \equiv dB \pmod n \\
      &\implies DdAx \equiv DdB \pmod n \\
      &\implies Ax \equiv B \pmod n \\
      &\implies \dfrac adx \equiv \dfrac bd \pmod n
\end{align}

Using the same sort of reasoning, we can also prove

THEOREM $2$. If

- $ax \equiv b \pmod n$
- $d \mid a$, $\ d\mid b$, and $d \mid n$

then
$\dfrac adx \equiv \dfrac bd \left( \mathrm{mod} \ \dfrac nd \right)$

Comment: *More conceptually:* $\,(d,n)=1\,\Rightarrow\bmod n\!:\ d^{-1}\ {\rm exists,\ so\ scaling\ }\, dax \equiv db\ $ by $\,d^{-1}$ yields $\,ax\equiv b,\,$ i.e. **invertible elements are always cancellable** (in any ring). The converse also holds by doing the *inverse* scaling by $\,(d^{-1})^{-1}\equiv d\,$. Generally scaling by units (invertibles) yields *equivalent* equations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat more conceptual way to think about @stevengregory 's correct answer.

Since $2$ and the modulus $5$ are relatively prime, $2$ has a multiplicative inverse $d \pmod{5}$. ($d$ happens to be $3$, but its value is irrelevant in this argument.)  Then multiplying both sides of the congruence
$$
4x \equiv 2 \pmod{5}
$$
by $d$ gives
$$
d \times 2 \times 2x \equiv d \times 2 \pmod{5} .
$$
But $d \times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ (that's what "multiplicative inverse" means) and the result you want follows.

In general, it's better to think about multiplication by inverses rather than division when working with congruences.

Comment: @OP Worth strong emphasis: it is essential to understand this conceptual *arithmetical* (vs. divisibility) viewpoint in order to master congruence arithemetic. As such I elaborate in my answer. Later this will be reified *algebraically* when one learns how to view $\,\Bbb Z_n \cong \Bbb Z/n\,$ as a *quotient ring*.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Scaling an equation by an element that is *cancellable* (e.g. a unit = invertible) always yields an $\rm\color{#c00}{equivalent}$ equation - see below. In your case $\bmod 5\!:\ a\equiv 2\,$ is a unit by $\,2\cdot 3\equiv 1$. Recall, [by Bezout:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) $\,a\,$ is a unit $\!\bmod n\!\iff\! \gcd(a,n) = 1$.

**Lemma** $\ \,ax\equiv b\iff x\equiv a^{-1}b\ $ when $\,a\,$ is a unit (invertible) $\ \ $ [**Unit Scaling $\rm\color{#c00}{Equivalence}$**]

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ \  ax&\equiv b\, \overset{\large \times\ a^{-1}\!}\Longrightarrow\, x\equiv a^{-1}b,\ \ \text{i.e. cancel $\,a\,$ by scaling by $\,a^{-1}$}\\
 (\Leftarrow)\ \ \   ax&\equiv b\, \overset{\large \times\ a}\Longleftarrow\,\ x\equiv a^{-1}b,\ \ \text{i.e. scale by}\,\ a\ \ \text{(= inverse of scaling by $\,a^{-1}$)}
\end{align}$

In both inferences above we applied the [Congruence Product Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3266937/242) for further elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

$4x \equiv  2\pmod 6$ (so $x$ could be $2\pmod 6$ or $x$ could be $5\pmod 6$) does not mean $2x \equiv 1\pmod 6$ (which is impossible).

But you can say

$ka \equiv kb \pmod n \implies a \equiv b \pmod {\frac n{\gcd(k, n)}}$

And so

$4x \equiv 2 \pmod 6$ meams $\frac {4x}2\equiv \frac 2{2}\pmod {\frac {6}{\gcd(2,6)}}$ or $2x =1 \pmod 3$ and that's fine. $x \equiv 2\pmod 3$ so $x\equiv 2\pmod 6$ or $x \equiv 3 \pmod 6$.

ANd to get to your problem:

$4x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ means

$\frac {4x}2 \equiv \frac 22 \pmod {\frac 5{\gcd(2,5)}}$ so

$2x \equiv 1 \pmod {\frac 51}$ and

$2x \equiv 1  \pmod  5$.

So you *CAN* but only because $2$ and $5$ are relatively prime.  You couldn't if they weren't.  (but you *could* if you devide the *modulus* but the gcd.)