# Divisibility by $17$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Express $n=10k+d$. i.e $d$ is the last digit of $n$.

I am wondering how I can prove this criterion

> $17|n $ if and only if $17|(3k+2d)$

I can prove the sufficient condition: $17|n$ iff $-10k\equiv d$ $(mod$ $17)$ , then $2d+3k\equiv2(-10k)+3k\equiv-17\equiv0$ $(mod$ $17)$.

But I got stuck proving the another side.

Comment: $\displaystyle\det\left(\begin{array}{rr}10& 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{array}\right) = \color{red}{17}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n=10k+d$$

$$10k+d \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$

Multiplying by $2$,

$$20k+2d\equiv 3k+2d \equiv 0\pmod{17}$$

---

Conversely, notice that $2$ and $17$ are coprime

If $3k+2d \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$, multiply both sides by $2^{-1}\pmod{17}$

$3(2^{-1})\equiv 10\pmod{17}$, we have $10k+d \equiv n \equiv  0 \pmod{17}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a nice answer which can be apply generally to proofs of similar criterion.

Comment: @xyz Yes, such scaling equivalences generalize to other divisibilty tests. I added an answer emphasizing the underlying arithmetical ideas to help make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that by eliminating one of the variables

$$10(3k+2d)-3(10k+d)=17d$$

$$2(10k+d)-(3k+2d)=17k$$

As the right hand side is divisible by $17,$

$$17\mid(3k+2d)\iff17|(10k+d)$$

Answer (score 1):

### $\begin{aligned} 10k+d \equiv 0 \pmod{17} &\underset{(*)}{\iff}\\ 20k+2d \equiv 0 \pmod{17} &\underset{(**)}{\iff}\\ 3k+2d \equiv 0 \pmod{17}\\ \end{aligned}$

$(*)$ Because $\gcd(2, 17) = 1$.

$(**)$ Because $20\equiv 3 \pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}{\rm Note}\,\   17\mid\:\! y-10x\iff&\, 17\mid 2y-3x,\ \ {\rm by}\\[.3em]
\bmod\, 17\!:\  y\equiv 10x\iff &\,2y\equiv \color{#c00}3x,\ \ \,\rm by\\[.3em]
   y\equiv 10x\iff &\,2y\equiv \color{#c00}{20}x\ \ \,{\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{20\equiv 3}
\end{align}\qquad$$

$(\Rightarrow)$ follows by scaling $\,y\equiv 10x\,$ by $2$. This scaling is is *invertible:* scale $\,2y\equiv \color{#c00}3x\,$ by $\,\frac{1}2 \equiv \frac{18}2\equiv 9$ to get $(\Leftarrow).\,$ Generally [scaling equations by units](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242) (invertibles) yields *equivalant* equations (for our case of $\,\Bbb Z_m = $ integers $\!\bmod m,\,$ [recall by Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) $\,a\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod m\iff \gcd(a,m)=1)$.

Said fractionally $\bmod 17\!:\ 10\equiv 3/2\,$ by $\,10\cdot 2\equiv 3.\,$ Generally such divisibility tests employ such modular fractions for $10$ (or $1/10$) that are "small", so to make the divisibility test convenient for hand calculation.

**Beware** $ $ Modular fractions $\,a/b := ab^{-1}$ are well-defined only for fractions whose denominator $\,b\,$ is *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion, and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) for many ways to calculate modular fractions and inverses.