# Find the smallest natural number $x$ which satisfies both $5x \equiv 4$ mod $13$ and $4x \equiv 5$ mod $17$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Using the multiplicative inverse of 5 (which I used $8$), and multiplying it to $5x \equiv 4$ mod $13$, I get $x \equiv 6$ mod $13$. From that I get $x=13k+6$. Plugging that into $4x \equiv 5$ mod $17$ and simplifying, I got $k\equiv 15$ mod $17$. And plugging that back into $x=13k+6$, I get $x=13\cdot 15 + 6 = 201$ as the smallest natural number.

Is $201$ the smallest natural number that is possible? How do I know I got the smallest natural number? I'm pretty sure what I did was correct but $201$ seems like a really high number.

Comment: Any two solutions would need to be congruent $\pmod {13\times 17}$ and $13\times 17=221>201$ so you got the least positive solution.

Comment: Deleted my answer as this question is a dupe

Comment: Scaling each by inverses of the coef of $x$ yields an equivalent system in standard CRT form, and by Easy CRT in the dupe we know that solutions are unique mod $13\cdot 17 = 221,\,$ so your solution $201$ is the unique nonnegative solution $< 221\ \ $

Comment: To elaborate: if there were also a smaller solution $\,x_1,\,$ i.e. $\,0\le x_1< 201\,,$ then this yields two *incongruent* solutions $\!\bmod 221,\,$ contra *uniqueness*. Here "solutions are unique $\!\bmod n$" means that if $\,x_1\,$ is a solution then every other solution $\,x_2\,$ is congruent to it $\,x_2\equiv x_1\pmod{\!n}.\ \ $

Comment: **Easier:** $\ 5^2\equiv -1\pmod{\!13},\ 4^2\equiv -1\pmod{\!17}\,$ so scaling the 1st by $\,-5\,$ and the 2nd by $\,-4\,$ yields  $\,x \equiv -20\pmod{ \! 13\ \&\ 17}$  $\iff x \equiv -20\equiv 201\pmod{\!221=13(17)}\,$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque if this question is a dupe then why answer again in the comments. Doesn't that just encourage more dupes?

Comment: @Mike For abstract dupes it is usually helpful to say a bit about  how the general result specializes (here CRT uniqueness). Note that what you wrote in your answer is not enough. We have to know that the transformation to CRT form yields an *equivalent* system, which is true here because [scaling a congruence by an invertible yields an equivalent congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242)

Comment: We can solve it *directly* your way (w/o CRT) if we keep careful track of *equivalences* between the transformed systems. Briefly: $\,x\,$ satisfies 1st congruence $\iff x=6+13j,\ j\in \Bbb Z.\,$ which satisfies the 2nd congreunce $\iff \color{#c00}{j = -2\! +\! 17k},\,$ so both initial congruences hold true $\iff x = 6\!+\!13\:\!\color{#c00}j =  6\!+\!13(\color{#c00}{-2\!+\!17k})=-20\!+\!221k,\ k\in\Bbb Z$ $\iff x\equiv -20\equiv 201\pmod{\!221}$