# Number of solutions to $89 x \equiv 7 \pmod{55}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How do I show that my solution to the congruence is the only solution?

I'm asked to solve, $\mu,\lambda$ that satisfy $$89 \lambda+55 \mu=1$$
Using Euclid's algorithm I found $\lambda=-21,\mu=34$.

Then I'm asked to find the solution to $$89 x \equiv 7\pmod{55}$$
Using $\lambda 89 \equiv1 \pmod{55}$

I found that $7\lambda89 \equiv7 \pmod{55} \implies x=7\lambda +55k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

**But how do I show, that this is the only solution to the congruence?**

Comment: The solution of $ax+b\equiv 0\pmod m$ is unique if $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

Comment: So, are $89$ and $55$ coprime?

Comment: @richrow So you're saying because $gcd(89,55)=1$ there is only one solution?  
Why is that the case? I don't have any theorems saying that. So I think I need to argue for that

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang yes they are.

Comment: The solution of a general linear congruence $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{n}\,$ is given in the linked dupe thread (as well as many others - see the Linked questions there). If you have specific questions about such then please ask in those threads first, and pose a new question only about the specific points that remain unclear (if you don't get adequate replies there). This helps to improve the quality of prior answers (and localizes information).

Comment: The uniqueness (and existence) of the solution are *explicitly* treated in [this dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419766/show-that-the-only-solution-of-the-congruence-equation-ax-equiv-b-pmodp-is). If you have further questions please post comments here or there.

Answer (score 0):

You found the multiplicative inverse of $89 \bmod {55}$.  It's $-21$.  Thus we get $89x\cong7\bmod{55}\iff x\cong -21\cdot7\bmod{55}\iff x\cong 18\bmod{55}$.

Comment: But that just gives me the same solution: $x=18+55k$ for  $k\in \mathbb{Z}$? If we set $k=-3$, we get $x=7\lambda$.

Comment: $k=-3\implies x=-147$.

Comment: Yes, and $x=-147=7(-21)=7\lambda$

Comment: Yes, but by multiplying on both sides of the congruence by $-21$ you prove all solutions are of the form $18+55k$.  So we have the infinite list $\{\dots,-147, -92,-37,18,73,\dots\}$.

Comment: I know. But what I'm asking is why that infinite list is the only solution. That's what I need to prove.

Comment: I don't understand how that proves that this is the only solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113181/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-sjm23).